# contract address returning '0x0000000000000000000000000000000000000000'

Tags: solidity, erc-20, ico

I am rying to get the address of public variable **tokenContract** of datatype contract but its returning the address as ''0x0000000000000000000000000000000000000000''   below is the code for the same

Smart Contract code

```
pragma solidity ^0.4.2;

/**
 * The AjTokenSale contract does this and that...
 */
 import './AjToken.sol';

contract AjTokenSale {
    address admin;
    AjToken public tokenContract;
    function AjTokenSale() public {
        //Assign an Admin
        admin = msg.sender;
        //Token contract
        //Set the Token Price

    }   
}
```

Test Code

```
var AjTokenSale = artifacts.require('./AjTokenSale.sol');
var AjToken  = artifacts.require('./AjToken.sol');
contract('AjTokenSale', function(accounts) {
    var tokenSaleInstance;

    it('Initializes the contract with the correct values', function() {
        return AjTokenSale.deployed().then(function(instance) {
            tokenSaleInstance = instance;
            return tokenSaleInstance
        }).then(function(address) {
            assert.notEqual(address,0x0, 'has contract address');
            return tokenSaleInstance.tokenContract();
        }).then(function(address) {
            //assert.equal(address, 0x0, 'Token contract has the address');
            assert.notEqual(address, 0x0, 'Token contract has the address');
        });
    });
});
```

When i am running above code test is failing on "Token contract has the address" it returns the assertion error as below,

"AssertionError: Token contract has the address: expected '0x0000000000000000000000000000000000000000' to not equal 0"

Really not sure , what is happening..

Need help..

Comment: I think the issue might be that you are treating `instance` as your address when you need to call/pass `instance.address`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are not even setting the `tokenContract` field in your smart contract. An unset field defaults to 0. You'll have to pass the address of the `tokenContract` to the constructor of `AJTokenSale` and store it.

Answer (score 1):

The type of `address` is `String`, not `Number`.

And this string typically stores the hexadecimal representation of a 40-digit `BigNumber`.

So you should change this:

```
assert.notEqual(address, 0x0, ...);
```

Either to this (string comparison):

```
assert(address != "0x" + "0".repeat(40), ...);
```

Or to this (numeric comparison):

```
assert(!web3.toBigNumber(address).equals(0), ...);
```

Comment: actually as per Henk , i was not assigning the value to my variable itself and when i did it worked. but as per your answer it is something that i am not able to understand..for your reference [link](https://youtu.be/XdKv5uwEk5A?t=12586) you can see it exactly used the same way i did and it passed. Any special reason for doing the way you have shown?

Comment: @user1576448: Of course it passed, but because every address that you receive will not be equal to `0x0`. It will pass for **every** address - zero or not, because `address` is of type `String` and `0x0` is of type `Number`. I'm pretty sure that this is not the kind of test that you desire, because it will not alert you for when your address is `"0x0000000000...0"`.